# Samba server - single user connection limit

Tags: linux, samba, network-share, file-sharing, server-message-block

Is there a limitation for samba server to allow multiple connection's from single user? (Multiple PC's connecting to same samba server with same account)
User was created through smbpasswd -a [username]

Server: AlmaLinux 9
Samba version: 4.16.4

Thank for any response

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with a bit of tricky way. You should add `preexec` script to check if this users is already connected:

```
[myshare]
    ...
    preexec script = /sbin/PermitSingleLogon.sh
    preexec close = Yes
    ...
```

And the script itself

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="-"
RESULT=$(smbstatus -S -u $1 2> /dev/null | awk 'NF \
        > 6 {print $1}' | sort | uniq -d)

if [ "X${RESULT}" == X  ]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

For more details please check the original [samba manual](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/samba_reference_guide/32_AdvancedNetworkManagement_09.html).